# How to run another python file and store/search it's output?

Tags: python, sqlmap

So I want to make an automatic SQL injector using sqlmap. 
What I want to do is after a SQL vulnerable link found it will launch sqlmap with parameters[ -u %s(vulnerable link) ] That's good. I think I'm going to do it with os.system(if there is better way please tell me). That part is ok.
But after that the sqlmap gives you database names. How can I catch that database names? Or maybe save all the output to a txt file and make it search for database names.(but it could be bad)

Comment: `os.system()` does not allow you to capture output, and is considered deprecated.  Sounds like you need the `subprocess` module.  There are a few examples in the doc, and many more on the web.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Could you show output of sqlmap? And the exact result you want to be stored in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure It will help you but you can export all Python output of a Python script. To do that you can set `sys.stdout` to an file object. Here an example:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test'
```